# Stuck with "IsMouseButtonPressed" condition

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

1. I've tryed write script with abortion at any time for LGHUB. Script pressing G1 Button, when i'm pressing G5, and releases G1, if i release G5.
2. I'm not very much experienced user of Lua, cos of it i used written code, but i understand logic and how this code works, but problem is, that script is aborting right at start like G5 released, but it is not. I read my script over and over, but i didnt understand what wrong in code.

For example, when i'm using "exiting = not IsModifierPressed("ctrl")" - it works as supposed, by unpressing control

Script, it's quite simple, let's take a look:

```lua
function OnEvent(event, gkey, family)
  OutputLogMessage(event, arg)

  if ((event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and gkey == 5) and IsModifierPressed("ctrl")
    and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")
    and IsModifierPressed("ctrl")) then

    repeat
      PressKey("c")
      Sleep(10)
      PressMouseButton(1)
      ReleaseKey("c")

      local tm = GetRunningTime()
      local exiting

      repeat
        Sleep(50)
        exiting = not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) --not working
      until exiting or GetRunningTime() - tm > 10000

      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
      Sleep(10)
    until exiting
  end
end
```

Thanks for help and ur attention!

Comment: What command (or macro) is assigned to the physical button G5?  You can see it on the big picture of mouse in GHUB.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff i get ur point. It's cause of i disabled the buttons at GHUB. Fixed that! Thank you, bro. Actually i often read ur helpings on Stack, u are tremendously helpful man! Спасибо, мужик)

Answer (score 0):

If u use "IsMouseButtonPressed" - be sure, that button is functional in GHUB app, i'm not sure about affection to script from binded macroses on button, whatever, if ur button has (for example G5) has default bind, this button be able to interract with "IsMouseButtonPressed", in other ways it s could not. Thanks for attention!